# Drop down menu only set value when it been opened again only on mobile and macos

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown

Hi i have a drop down menu on my website .. it looks like this

```js
<div class="box">
    <p>Kerület</p>
    <select name="type" class="input"   onclick="districtButtonClick(value)"  required>
       <option class="btn" value="all" >Összes</option>
       <option class="btn" value="I">I</option>
       <option class="btn" value="II">II</option>
       <option class="btn" value="III" value="III">III</option>
       <option class="btn" value="IV">IV</option>
       <option class="btn" value="V">V</option>
       <option class="btn" value="VI">VI</option>
       <option class="btn" value="VII">VII</option>
       <option class="btn" value="VIII">VIII</option>
       <option class="btn" value="IX">IX</option>
       <option class="btn" value="X">X</option>
       <option class="btn" value="XI">XI</option>
       <option class="btn" value="XII">XII</option>
       <option class="btn" value="XIII">XIII</option>
       <option class="btn" value="XIV">XIV</option>
       <option class="btn" value="XV">XV</option>
       <option class="btn" value="XVI">XVI</option>
       <option class="btn" value="XVII">XVII</option>
       <option class="btn" value="XVIII">XVIII</option>
       <option class="btn" value="XIX">XIX</option>
       <option class="btn" value="XX">XX</option>
       <option class="btn" value="XXI">XXI</option>
       <option class="btn" value="XXII">XXII</option>
       <option class="btn" value="XXIII">XXIII</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

it calls a function for a onClick event and pass a value to the function.... on the desktop it works perfectly.
But when i try it on mobile devices (both android and iPhone) or in macOs, i select a number which apears in the drop down menu as if i selected it, but the function doesnt seems to trigger, only if i reopen the drop down menu..

heres the website on the server if you want to give it a try
http://adingatlan.fejlessz.hu/a/index.html
all search such as Utca which means street kerulet is District
and on the bottom line theres a min and max price works on desktop but on mobile athe district doesnt seems to work

heres the js function as well but i dont think this is the problem

```js
function districtButtonClick(buttonNumber){

        console.log(buttonNumber);

        let item = grid.querySelectorAll('.box');
        //filter = e.target.dataset.filter;
        filter = buttonNumber;
       
        if (filter == "all") {
            districtBool = false;
        } else {
            districtBool = true;
        }
        
        //console.log(filter);
 

        //console.log(item.length);
    
        
            if(streetSearchEmpty == true && maxPriceBool == false && minPriceBool == false){
                district = districtSearch(filter, item);
                console.log(" Kerulet Kereses ");
            }

            if(streetSearchEmpty == false){
                di = searchStreet(searchValue, item);
                didi = districtSearch(filter, di);
                console.log(" Kerulet Kereses Utcaval");

                if(maxPriceBool == true || minPriceBool == true) {



                    priceSearched = priceSort(minPriceValue, maxPriceValue, didi);
                    streetPrice = districtSearch(filter, priceSearched);
                    console.log(" Kerulet Kereses Utcaval majd arral");

                }
            }

            else if (maxPriceBool == true || minPriceBool == true) {

                du = priceSort(minPriceValue, maxPriceValue, item);
                dudu = districtSearch(filter, du);
                console.log(" Kerulet Kereses arral");

                if (streetSearchEmpty == false) {

                    if(streetPrice.length == 0) {

                    streetsearched = searchStreet(searchValue, dudu);
                    streetPrice = districtSearch(filter, streetsearched);
                    console.log(" Kerulet Kereses arral majd uccaval");
      
            }}
        }
                
}
```

Comment: Please post the JS that you are using to make this work

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event - the parameter is populated by the system... you should not use "value" as a parameter...

Comment: i also added a console.log("triggered"); print to my javascript function and it seems that on pc desktop it triggers when i click on the dropdown and also when i am selecting a value.. on macos it only print when i click on the drop down but not  when i select the value... did anybody had the same issue? it also looks different, i already  tried to add

   -webkit-appearance: none;
   appearance:none;

to the css file but it doesnt seems to work

Comment: @ThisGuy

I also tryed to use data-filter="" ...but it didnt work with that eighter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oclick() doesnt work on mobile because the select is natively rendered in some mobile browsers

[onchange()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) should do the trick.

use it like this:

```html
<div class="box">
        <p>Kerület</p>
        <select name="type" class="input"   onchange="districtButtonClick($event)"  required>
           <option class="btn" value="all" >Összes</option>
           <option class="btn" value="I">I</option>
    ...
```

and then in js something along:

```js
districtButtonClick(event){
   console.log("selected value:", event.target.value);
}
```

Comment: thank you .. i tried and i got an error  "$event is not defined"

Comment: ok so i changed the event to value and it works perfectly thank you very much ... i doesnt even had to change the js file at all .. only used the onchange instead of onclick